# Gallery doesn't load properly first time, only after reload

Tags: wordpress, image, gallery, reload

I have a question regarding the website I'm building through Wordpress. I have an image gallery on my page. Only, the first time I load the page, the gallery doesn't show properly. Only after I reload the page, it shows properly.

You can have a look here: https://www.jorishilterman.com/projecten/

Does anyone recognise the problem and knows what I should do?

Best, Anne

Comment: its showing properly for me. I dint find any misaligmment

Comment: for me also its showing properly but for the gallery its taking more time to load i think its because of the image Size. In which browser you checked.

Comment: I believe you mean after page is loaded, if you switch to the other language by clicking on the "read in xxx" link the gallery does not work. I can see after language change, the gallery is not adding dynamic CSS (like position: absolute; left: 33.2487%; top: 20px;) to each thumbnail.

Try switching to some other gallery layout than masonry. See what happens.

Comment: Also, what is responsible for the language change functionality?

Comment: I have checked in Firefox as well as chrome but gallery are showing properly. i think you need to clear your browser cache and then check. i think is its showing properly.

Comment: you need to reinisialized the masonory on ready document